# Use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on python with dynamic tables

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use a query directly on python to update my database, but I need to do a lot of time in different table:

```
def load_data(self, path, table):
    print table
    print path
    cursor = self.mariadb_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(" LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %s INTO TABLE %s"
                   " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
                   " ENCLOSED BY '"'"
                   " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
                   " ignore 1 lines ",
                   (path, table))
```

The function do not recognize the third line and when I put like a comment the query do not understand the table. Have another way to do this query?

Comment: the `"` inside `ENCLOSED BY '"'"` is ending the Python string. You need to escape it.

Comment: Yes, that is right but the data is enclosed on this way. I need to have another action or modification before this

Comment: You need to escape it so you have correct Python string syntax.

Comment: `" ENCLOSED BY '\"'"`

Comment: "ENCLOSED BY '""' "

Comment: In this way worked, but I still have problems to insert the table

Comment: @Barmar I had problem using in your way. It did not work for me :/. The data was considered that was truncated so it did not find the data inside .txt

Comment: You may also need to escape the backslash in `\n`. Try using a raw string.

Comment: @Barmar I would like to do this, but the file came already done. I need to modificate all the file.

Comment: cursor.execute(" LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %s INTO TABLE " + str(table) + ""
                           " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
                           " ENCLOSED BY '""' "
                          " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' "
                          " ignore 1 lines ",
                          (path))

Comment: In this way worked but mariadb did not receive the data

Answer (score 0):

Below follow the solution that I found:

```
cursor = self.mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE % s"
                "INTO TABLE " + str(table) + " "
                "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' "
                "ENCLOSED BY '\"' "
                "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' "
                "ignore 1 lines ",
                   path)
self.mariadb_connection.commit()
```

The three quotes could be a very good solution for a standard database, but I do  not know why the query on mariadb is not allowed when we use a dynamic table (using %s to call a table).

Another thing the program accept the changes only after the commit.

The only solutions that fits for me was this one. Thank you for your support.